# java programming with this class

Tags: java

Hey I'm writing a java class and the result has to be from this image

[image].

The whole program works great but in the end i don't get the correct math output. I think it some problem in my equation. Can someone help me with the problem. Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Sports
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         //create scanner object
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

            //create tolkit object
            Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
           int players;
           int team=15;

           System.out.println("SporT's Team Calculator");
           System.out.println("=======================");

           System.out.println("Enter the Total number of players===>");
           players=input.nextInt(); 


           System.out.println("Enter the Number of players per team" +
           "\n(at least 9 & no more than 15 per team)===>");
           players=input.nextInt(); 



       while(players>15 || players<9  )
         {
           tk.beep();
           System.out.println("\nInvalid number of players per team, please re-enter...");

           System.out.println("Enter the Number of players per team" +
                   "\n(at least 9 & no more than 15 per team)===>");
           players=input.nextInt(); 

           players=players%team;


           }
       System.out.println("There will be " + players + " teams, "
               + "with " + players + " players " + "left over."); 

       System.out.println("\nThank you for using SporT's Software!");


    } 

}
```

Comment: What output do you get? What did you see when you **debugged** the code?

Comment: Type out the text rather than using an image. In fact, you could simplify this question far more. Put more effort into your questions; you'll get better answers and you'll often solve them for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving both the total number of players and the number of players on a team into the same variable `players`. If you were to answer that the total number of players is 142 it'll immediately be overwritten by the next assignment to players for the number per team. These should be separate variables `int playersPerTeam` for instance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are retrieving two pieces of information: the total number of players and the players per team. So you will need two variables to store both pieces of information. Instead of overriding the same variable - losing the first piece of information collected.

The Equations:

To get the number of teams:

```
(int)(players / playerPerTeam)
```

To get the number of left over players:

```
players-playerPerTeam*totalTeams
```

Also I don't understand why you are getting two different numbers, `11` and `10`, for the same variable, `players` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are working with java so the variable
        players
will constantly gets overridden.

To solve this, divide the variable

```
    players
```

into 2 different variables, one to count the number of players(total) and another to count the number of players per team. This also means that you will need to change the part when you continuously ask the user for a valid input set (in the while loop) .

Secondly, your math in calculating your total number of teams and the players left over are incorrect. Below, I included a working version:

```
    int numTeams = totalPlayers / playersPerTeam;
    int playersLeft = totalPlayers - (playersPerTeam * numTeams);
    System.out.println("There will be " + numTeams + " teams, " + "with " + playersLeft + " players " + "left over.");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i actually already figured it out but thanks.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Sports
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         //create scanner object
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

            //create tolkit object
            Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
           int players;
           int team;

           System.out.println("SporT's Team Calculator");
           System.out.println("=======================");

           System.out.println("Enter the Total number of players===>");
           players=input.nextInt(); 


           System.out.println("Enter the Number of players per team" +
           "\n(at least 9 & no more than 15 per team)===>");
           team=input.nextInt(); 




       while(team>15 || team<9  )
         {
           tk.beep();
           System.out.println("\nInvalid number of players per team, please re-enter...");

           System.out.println("Enter the Number of players per team" +
                   "\n(at least 9 & no more than 15 per team)===>");
           team=input.nextInt(); 




           }

       int result=players/team;
       int player= players%team;

       System.out.println("There will be " + result + " teams, "
               + "with " + player + " players" + " left over."); 

       System.out.println("\nThank you for using SporT's Software!");


    } 

}
```